# NoMethodError in Reviews#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

i am trying to write a new review that is nested inside resturants but i keep getting no method error in reviews# new action. i keep getting a red line on the reviews form

```
<%= form_with(model: [@review, @resturant] , local: true) do |form| %>
```

The Full Error Message:

> ```
> NoMethodError in Reviews#new
> Showing /Users/AHmed/Desktop/burgerland-ar/app/views/reviews/_form.html.erb
> ```
>
> where line #1 raised:
>
> ```
> undefined method `review_resturant_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f8b3abe3170>:0x007f8b3abe04e8>
> Did you mean?  resturant_reviews_path
>                resturant_review_path
>                new_resturant_path
> ```

Did the new rails 5 syntax changed or the error is with the reviews controller ? Here's my code:

**reviews/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: [@review, @resturant] , local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if review.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(review.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this review from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% review.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :rating %>
    <%= form.number_field :rating, id: :review_rating %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :comment %>
    <%= form.text_area :comment, id: :review_comment %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**/reviews_controller.rb**

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_review, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
   before_action :set_resturant
  before_action :authenticate_user!



  # GET /reviews/new
  def new
    @review = Review.new
  end

  # GET /reviews/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /reviews
  # POST /reviews.json
  def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.user_id = current_user.id
    @review.resturant_id = @resturant.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @review.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Review was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @review }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /reviews/1
  # PATCH/PUT /reviews/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @review.update(review_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @review, notice: 'Review was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @review }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /reviews/1
  # DELETE /reviews/1.json
  def destroy
    @review.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to reviews_url, notice: 'Review was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_review
      @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_resturant
      @resturant = Resturant.find(params[:resturant_id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :comment)
    end
end
```

**rake routes**

```
                 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                          Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                             devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                             devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                            devise/sessions#destroy
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                        devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                       devise/passwords#edit
           user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                            devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                            devise/passwords#update
                         POST   /users/password(.:format)                            devise/passwords#create
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                              devise/registrations#cancel
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                             devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                devise/registrations#edit
       user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                                     devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                                     devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                                     devise/registrations#destroy
                         POST   /users(.:format)                                     devise/registrations#create
       resturant_reviews POST   /resturants/:resturant_id/reviews(.:format)          reviews#create
    new_resturant_review GET    /resturants/:resturant_id/reviews/new(.:format)      reviews#new
   edit_resturant_review GET    /resturants/:resturant_id/reviews/:id/edit(.:format) reviews#edit
        resturant_review PATCH  /resturants/:resturant_id/reviews/:id(.:format)      reviews#update
                         PUT    /resturants/:resturant_id/reviews/:id(.:format)      reviews#update
                         DELETE /resturants/:resturant_id/reviews/:id(.:format)      reviews#destroy
              resturants GET    /resturants(.:format)                                resturants#index
                         POST   /resturants(.:format)                                resturants#create
           new_resturant GET    /resturants/new(.:format)                            resturants#new
          edit_resturant GET    /resturants/:id/edit(.:format)                       resturants#edit
               resturant GET    /resturants/:id(.:format)                            resturants#show
                         PATCH  /resturants/:id(.:format)                            resturants#update
                         PUT    /resturants/:id(.:format)                            resturants#update
                         DELETE /resturants/:id(.:format)                            resturants#destroy
                    root GET    /                                                    resturants#index
             pages_about GET    /pages/about(.:format)                               pages#about
              pages_help GET    /pages/help(.:format)                                pages#help
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  resources :resturants do 
  resources :reviews , except: [:index,:show]
end
  root 'resturants#index'
  get 'pages/about'

  get 'pages/help'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: Post your `rake routes` results

Comment: i have added the rake routes

Comment: Please post the complete error message

Comment: How does your routes look like? Please add the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> undefined method `review_resturant_path' for
>   <#<Class:0x007f8b3abe3170>:0x007f8b3abe04e8>

You need to switch the order of `@review` and `@resturant` like below

```
<%= form_with(model: [@resturant, @review] , local: true) do |form| %>
```

so it generates the *correct routes* helper

**Explanation:**

While building the form for *nested resources*, make sure you put the *resources(model instances)* in a **correct order**. Yes, the order matters!

`[@review, @resturant] #=>` generates `review_resturant_path` which is **Incorrect**

`[@resturant, @review] #=>` generates `resturant_reviews_path` which is **correct**

Alternatively, If you feel the order is confusing, you can use the *route helper* generated which servers the same purpose. So the form will look like below

```
<%= form_with url: resturant_reviews_path(@resturant) do |form| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

> NoMethodError in Reviews#new

Which is **wrong path**

```
<%= form_with(model: [@review, @resturant] , local: true) do |form| %>
```

Look at your routes you have `resturant_reviews_path` which one is **correct** so

You should do like this :

```
<%= form_with(model: [@resturant, @review] , local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if review.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(review.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this review from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% review.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :rating %>
    <%= form.number_field :rating, id: :review_rating %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :comment %>
    <%= form.text_area :comment, id: :review_comment %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```